# Group Information in joined table for last available year

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I have this table with an unique identifier and its group; I want to get totals of another table based on its Group

Table 1

```
UNIQUE_ID ! Group

      1     West 
      2     West 
      3     West 
      4     West 
      5     West 
      6     East 
      7     East
```

Then I have this second table from with which I join

Table 2

```
UNIQUE_ID ! NET PROFIT ! ASSETS ! EQUITY ! YEAR

       1     100           100     100     2016  
       1     100           100     100     2015  
       2     100           100     100     2016 
       2     100           100     100     2015  
       3     100           100     100     2016  
       3     100           100     100     2015  
    ***4     10            10      10      2015*** 
       5     100           100     100     2016  
       5     100           100     100     2015   
    ***6     10            10      10      2014*** 
       7     100           100     100     2016  
       7     100           100     100     2015
       7     100           100     100     2014
```

I link the previous tables and I group by Group which then gives me the totals for NEt profit, assets and equity, the problem is that it sums all the years available in table 2 Or I do a where year is 2016 and I only get the totals from 2016 not including the rows which id have the latest year of 2015 or 2014

I need it to group by Group and sum only the last available year for each unique ID, so that I would get the following table

Query would give me this table

```
Group ! NET PROFIT ! ASSETS ! EQUITY
 East      410        410      410
 West      110        110      110
```

Can anyone help me? I've looked everywhere and tried a number of combinations but without success

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Microsoft Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a join of an aggregate derived table to the join of other two tables where essentially the last `INNER JOIN` acts as a `WHERE` clause to filter select years for each *unique_id*.

```
SELECT t1.`GROUP`, SUM(t2.NET_PROFIT) AS SUM_NET_PROFIT, 
                   SUM(t2.ASSETS) AS SUM_ASSETS, 
                   SUM(t2.EQUITY) AS SUM_EQUITY
FROM (`table2` t2
INNER JOIN `table1` t1
   ON t1.UNIQUE_ID = t2.UNIQUE_ID)       
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT t2.UNIQUE_ID, MAX(t2.`YEAR`) AS MAX_YEAR
   FROM `table2` t2
   GROUP BY t2.UNIQUE_ID) g    
ON t2.`UNIQUE_ID` = g.`UNIQUE_ID` AND t2.`YEAR` = g.`MAX_YEAR`    
GROUP BY t1.`GROUP`;
```

Do note the parentheses used to wrap first join pairing of tables, required in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Group_,
       SUM(NET_PROFIT) AS NET_PROFIT_YR,
       SUM(ASSETS) AS ASSETS_YR,
       SUM(EQUITY) As EQUITY_YR
  FROM Table1 AS T1
 INNER
  JOIN (SELECT T2_RAW.*
          FROM ( SELECT Unique_ID,
                        MAX(year) AS m_year
                   FROM Table2 AS T2
                  GROUP
                     BY Unique_ID
               ) AS MYR
         INNER
          JOIN Table2 AS T2_RAW
            ON MYR.unique_id = T2_RAW.unique_id
           AND MYR.m_year = T2_RAW.year
       ) AS TMP
    ON T1.unique_id = TMP.unique_id
 GROUP
    BY group_;
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I. The complete SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    ta.group,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.net_profit, 0)) as sumNetProfit,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.assets, 0)) as sumAssets,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.equity, 0)) as sumEquity
FROM table_a AS ta
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        unique_id,
        max(year) as maxYear
    FROM table_b
    GROUP BY unique_id
) AS tbMaxYears ON tbMaxYears.unique_id = ta.unique_id
LEFT JOIN table_b AS tb ON 
    tb.unique_id = ta.unique_id
    AND tb.year = tbMaxYears.maxYear
GROUP BY ta.group;
```

#### II. Description:

**The inner query:**

```
SELECT 
    unique_id,
    max(year) as maxYear
FROM table_b
GROUP BY unique_id
```

- Selects the `unique_id`s from `table_b` and, for each `unique_id`, the corresponding latest year, e.g. the maximal year;
- Groups the fetched records by the `unique_id`;
- Is used in a `LEFT JOIN` statement under the alias `maxYears` and its results are filtered by the `unique_id`s fetched from the `table_a`.

The inner query results looks like following:

```
unique_id   maxYear
-------------------
1           2016
2           2016
3           2016
4           2015
5           2016
6           2014
7           2016
```

**The outer query:**

```
SELECT 
    ta.group,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.net_profit, 0)) as sumNetProfit,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.assets, 0)) as sumAssets,
    SUM(IFNULL(tb.equity, 0)) as sumEquity
FROM table_a AS ta
LEFT JOIN (
    <THE-INNER-QUERY-RESULTS>
) AS tbMaxYears ON tbMaxYears.unique_id = ta.unique_id
LEFT JOIN table_b AS tb ON 
    tb.unique_id = ta.unique_id
    AND tb.year = tbMaxYears.maxYear
GROUP BY ta.group;
```

- Reads all `table_a` records;
- Attaches the `maxYears` details (fetched through the inner query);
- Attaches the `table_b` details;
- Groups the records by the `group` column;
- Calculates the corresponding sums (including NULL values validation).

The results of the outer query (e.g. the final results):

```
group   sumNetProfit    sumAssets   sumEquity
---------------------------------------------
East    110             110         110
West    410             410         410
```

**The second LEFT JOIN in the outer query:**

```
LEFT JOIN table_b AS tb ON 
    tb.unique_id = ta.unique_id
    AND tb.year = tbMaxYears.maxYear
```

- Attaches (joins) the `table_b` details to the records fetched from `table_a`;
- Only the `table_b` records are attached, which have the same `unique_id` as the corresponding `unique_id` value from `table_a` AND (!) the same `year` as the corresponding `maxYear` value from `maxYears` table.

#### III. Used table structure:

I used a MySQL database with the following CREATE TABLE syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `unique_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `unique_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_profit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assets` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `equity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I used the same data as you.

Good luck!

Comment: Love your answer, super detailed! now I understand why it wasn't working and how I should query it

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.